# Rename mysql database when you have two databases with same name but with different cases

Tags: mysql

I have two myql databases with same name but with different case like Database_V1 and database_v1
when I'm trying to rename database_v1 to something like database_v1_test I'm getting error. I guess having two databases with same name is causing this issue. Is there a way in mysql to target database based on object id rather than schema name? PS I'm using Dbeaver at the moment for this operation.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the name in "quotes"?

Comment: *I'm getting error* - when asking for help with something that isn't working because of an error, the single most useful piece of info you can give the person interested in helping you, is the full exact text of the error message. Please never again use the phrase "i got an error". Always fully say exactly what the error message is

Comment: Renaming databases is not possible regardless of the case. The only option is to dump, edit dump file, then restore

Comment: @CaiusJard I guess this is DBeaver related. even when I'm double clicking the database for creating a new query its selecting the the lower case one.